# How to toggle visibility of NSView + Resize sibling view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nsview

We have a parent `Main` view (`NSView`), and two children views, `Content` and `StatusBar` (one above the other; both simple NSViews).

What would be the optimal Cocoa-friendly way to toggle the `StatusBar` view?

- I would really love it, if the suggested solution includes animation
- I really don't need any suggestions related to external plugins, etc (e.g. BWToolkit)

**Edit :**

As for the resizing part :

- When `StatusBar` view goes away, the `Content` view should EITHER occupy its place (optimal way) OR have the `Main` view shrink accordingly
- The above scenario, inversed.

Comment: Well... downvotes, without an explanation... really defeat their purpose... :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So, I've thought about it over and over again, and that's what I've managed; a category on NSView for toggling views... :-)

**Header :**

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

#define DIRECTION_UP        0
#define DIRECTION_RIGHT     1
#define DIRECTION_DOWN      2
#define DIRECTION_LEFT      3

@interface NSView (NSView_Functions)

- (void)toggleWithView:(NSView*)mainView usingDirection:(int)direction;

@end
```

**Implementation :**

```
#import "NSView+Functions.h"

@implementation NSView (NSView_Functions)

- (void)toggleWithView:(NSView*)mainView usingDirection:(int)direction 
{
    NSRect mr = [mainView frame];
    NSRect sr = [self frame];

    #ifdef DEBUG

    NSLog(@"MR @ %f,%f (%f X %f)",mr.origin.x,mr.origin.y,mr.size.width,mr.size.height);
    NSLog(@"SR @ %f,%f (%f X %f)",sr.origin.x,sr.origin.y,sr.size.width,sr.size.height);

    #endif

    NSRect newMr;

    CGFloat newX;
    CGFloat newY;
    CGFloat newWidth;
    CGFloat newHeight;

    switch (direction) {
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
            newX = mr.origin.x;
            newY = mr.origin.y;
            newHeight = mr.size.height;

            if (![self isHidden]) newWidth = mr.size.width + sr.size.width;
            else newWidth = mr.size.width - sr.size.width;

            break;

        case DIRECTION_DOWN:
            newX = mr.origin.x;
            newWidth = mr.size.width;

            if (![self isHidden]) 
            {
                newY = mr.origin.y-sr.size.height;
                newHeight = mr.size.height+sr.size.height;
            }
            else {
                newY = mr.origin.y+sr.size.height;
                newHeight = mr.size.height-sr.size.height;
            }

            break;

        case DIRECTION_LEFT:
            newY = mr.origin.y;
            newHeight = mr.size.height;

            if (![self isHidden]) 
            {
                newX = mr.origin.x-sr.size.width;
                newWidth = mr.size.width+sr.size.width;
            }
            else {
                newX = mr.origin.x+sr.size.width;
                newWidth = mr.size.width-sr.size.width;
            }

            break;

        case DIRECTION_UP:
            newX = mr.origin.x;
            newY = mr.origin.y;
            newWidth = mr.size.width;

            if (![self isHidden]) newHeight = mr.size.height + sr.size.height;
            else newHeight = mr.size.height - sr.size.height;

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    newMr = NSMakeRect(newX,newY,newWidth,newHeight);

    if (![self isHidden]) [self setHidden:YES]; else [self setHidden:NO];

    [mainView setFrame:newMr];
}

@end
```